Why must a reducible KG-module of dimension 2 have a KG-submodule of dimension 1?
I'm trying to see this with the Quaternion group $Q_8 = \langle a,b \ | \ a^2=b^2,\ bab^{-1} = a^{-1}   \rangle $, and the representation $\rho: Q_8 \rightarrow GL_2 (\mathbb{C}) $ defined by $\rho(a)=A $ and $\rho(b) = B$, where
$A= \begin{pmatrix}
i & 0\\
0 & -i
\end{pmatrix}$  and $ B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ . We want to show that $\rho$ is irreducible by assuming for contradiction that it is reducible as a $\mathbb{C}Q_8$-module. I've verified that it is indeed a $\mathbb{C}Q_8$-module from the most natural linear action, $v \mapsto \rho(g) \cdot v$ where $g\in Q_8 $ and $v \in \mathbb{C}^2$. Now, at the beginning, the proof says: $\rho$ is a 2-dimensional representation, hence, if it is reducible it must have a 1-dimensional subrepresentation. It then says such a representation is of the form $\mathbb{C}u$ for some nonzero $u \in \mathbb{C}^2$, which must be a simultaneous eigenvector of both $A$ and $B$. How do we know this?

A reducible representation has to have a proper subrepresentation, by definition. What dimension could such a thing have?

i get it now; since it is a proper subspace, if the dimension was 2 then it would just be equal to the space itself. But why must the basis of this subspace be a simultaneous eigenvector of both A and B?

That condition is equivalent to it being a subrepresentation (not just a subspace).
